# Search usando Solr no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algoritmo-de-busca, apache-solr

Se eu pesquisar por um pedaço de uma palavra que não seja seja os caracteres primeiros da palavra ele não acha. Tipo se eu pesquisar por "Car" ele busca corretamente, mas agora se eu buscar por "los" ou "arlos" me retorna vazio.

Tenho na tabela Client:

```
id  name
 1  Carlos da Silva
 2  Tiago Casanova
 3  Pedro Gomes
```

No meu modelo:

```
searchable  do
    text :name
end
```

No controller:

```
@clients = Client.search do
 fulltext params[:search]
 paginate :page => params[:page] || 1
end
```

No meu schema.xml

```
 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" />
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" />   
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para o tipo de busca que você quer vejo duas alternativas

1) Fazer em tempo de query um complemento na sua busca com os * dos dois lados assim o SOLR deve buscar usando a cadeia:

```
@clients = Client.search do
 fulltext "*#{params[:search]}*"
 paginate :page => params[:page] || 1
end
```

2) O tokenizer que você está usando é o **solr.StandardTokenizerFactory**, caso você queria reindexar usando outro tokenizer você pode usar o **solr.NGramTokenizerFactory** com min e o max da cadeia. Assim ele vai indexar as palavras por cadeias, você pode especificar o tamanho máximo e minimo da cadeia, só cuidado para não colocar um máximo muito pequeno.

Para mais exemplos segue documentação do solar, para o tópico de tokenizer

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-N-GramTokenizer